# Prevent URL to be seen in network console in 'Chrome/Firebug'

Tags: php, curl, https, http-headers

Can you make someone to visit a HTTPS URL (for example https://graph.facebook.com/Enrique') via an iFrame/Script tag, and the visitor still don't know what was the URL which got downloaded even if they check the 'Network Console' or something,

I'm free to use PHP 'headers' of something like that, but I would like to stay away from 'cURL' at server side, 'cause all I want is to make the visitor visit the URL with his own proxy to execute that url not my server(for preventing server load)

Comment: I just want to hide the URL being visited, with a fake uRL or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. There are methods of obfuscating it to make it harder to understand, but nothing bulletproof. Perhaps you could try URL encoding the text parts. For example:

https://graph.facebook.com/%45%6e%72%69%71%75%65

(I think chrome automatically replaces unnecessarily url-encoded characters.)

Here's some javascript that does this transform, I'm sure you could work up something similiar in PHP.

```
function percentEncodeAllChars(str) {

    var strEncoded = '';

    for(var i = 0, ilen = str.length; i < ilen; i++) {

        var strHex = parseInt(str.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16);
        strEncoded += '%' + strHex;
    }

    return strEncoded;
}

function doEncode() {

    var strInput = document.getElementById('encode').value;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = percentEncodeAllChars(strInput);
}
```

[Source](http://2tap.com/2009/12/06/percent-encoding-aka-url-encoding-all-characters/)

Comment: No. Headers are something worked out between the browser and the server. I assume that the server you are trying to get data off of is not one you control.

Answer (score 0):

No; that's completely impossible.

Comment: What about http redirects? in such a way that URL being fake but the request isn't

Comment: @PriyaSharma: There is no way to prevent the user from seeing a URL that his computer is requesting.